# DotNetOpenAuth with wrong versions

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

`DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet` v4.1 uses `DotNetOpenAuth.Core` v4.1 - and I've no idea where `DotNetOpenAuth.Core` v4.1 is?

The AspNet library was on NuGet and uploaded recently, this is driving me nuts - why upload a library with a version where it's dependencies are only available in lower version numbers.

The reason I'm going for v4.1 is that I was using v4.0 until recently, when I began get a Facebook Connect issue and I wanted to see if v4.1 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use NuGet to install DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet and all its dependencies will install automatically.